# Pinecone node js error: TypeError - PineconeClient is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, pinecone

I followed the docs: https://github.com/pinecone-io/pinecone-ts-client

I installed it via:

```
npm install @pinecone-database/pinecone
```

I've also set the following environmental variables:

```
PINECONE_API_KEY="your_api_key"
PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT="your_environment"
```

And then I have:

```
const PineconeClient = require('@pinecone-database/pinecone')
const pinecone = new PineconeClient();
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError - PineconeClient is not a constructor
```

Why is that the case? I'm following the docs but I'm getting the error?

The version of pinecone I have:

```
"@pinecone-database/pinecone": "^1.1.2"
```

And my node version is:

```
v20.9.0
```

Comment: `const {Pinecone:PineconeClient} = require('@pinecone-database/pinecone')` because the same docs has a sample snippet where the class is an attribute *inside* of what is imported... essentially, [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: How do I go about fixing it then?

Comment: the example snippet should make calling `new PineconeClient()` work ;-; as it is an example of destructuring it with the variable name you desire... conversely you can also do `const PineconeClient = require('@pinecone-database/pinecone').Pinecone` as well

Comment: .... @mark did you try what was suggested by the bomb squad? That's the solution you should try.

Comment: That worked thanks guys